# Why does the SQlite function executemany run slow with updating large amount of data?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, textblob

I'm new to SQlite and I ran into a problem while trying to update 2 columns of a SQlite database for a sentiment analysis on tweets using the TextBlob library. I have to update 6.5 million rows and I want to do it as efficiently as possible. I used the following code for this.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('tweets.db')
c = conn.cursor() 

from textblob import TextBlob

english_query = """
    SELECT tweet_id, text
    FROM tweetInfo
    WHERE lang = 'en'
"""
c.execute(english_query)
e_tweets = c.fetchall()
conn.commit()

data_list = []

for i in range(len(e_tweets)):
    small_list = [TextBlob(e_tweets[i][1]).sentiment.polarity, TextBlob(e_tweets[i][1]).sentiment.subjectivity, 
                    e_tweets[i][0]]
    data_list.append(small_list)

update_query = '''
    UPDATE tweetInfo
    SET polarity = ?, subjectivity = ?
    WHERE tweet_id = ?
'''
data = data_list 
c.executemany(update_query, data)
conn.commit()
```

I used the executemany function because I found online that it was suppossed to be fast with handeling large amount of data. The code seems to work fine, but it takes multiple hours to finish, so I'm wondering if I did anything wrong here with the executemany function or the code in general. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: 6.5 billion rows and sqlite? You do this wrong

Comment: Have you profiled the code to find the bottleneck(s)?

Comment: Not to mention storing DB in RAM

Comment: `executemany` in sqlite just executes multiple single `insert` statements (try setting `conn.set_trace_callback(print)` (but not for  6bn rows)).  It's  a convenience rather than an optimisation.  Some DB API connectors may provide optimised `executemany` methods, but not the stdlib's sqlite3.

Comment: Is `tweet_id` the primary key (or at least an indexed column)?

Comment: (you might try adding user-defined sql functions that compute the values and use them in a single update statement. `update tweetinfo set polarity = compute_polarity(text), ... where lang = 'en'`)

Comment: I would suggest several things to do: 1)try a transaction block 2) add an index to original table on tweet id (this is definitely going to help)